# How can I extract a parameter named "action" from the url without having to manually parse the querystring in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a site entry controller that is used via a url generated by a single sign on manager.  The SSO manager appends an identifying hash as an action parameter to the url of the system it is attempting to sign on to.

So the url being generated by the SSO manager looks like:

```
http://mysite/Entry/SingleSignOn?action=123456789ABCDEFG
```

I think I just need to set up a better route, but I haven't been able to get it to work yet.  When I try to get the action from the url via standard MVC binding, it is giving me the name of the action, not the hash I need:

```
 public ActionResult SingleSignOn(string action)
 {
     // action returns "SingleSignOn"
     var querystring = Request.Url.Query; //returns "?action=123456789ABCDEFG"
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

I know I can just split open the querystring, but would prefer not to if possible.  It doesn't seem like a terribly complex problem, but I am just not finding the right route.

Comment: The routing that is built in to MVC doesn't utilize the query string at all. So it is not very clear what you are trying to achieve. If the SSO sends all requests back to `/Entry/SingleSignOn`, then you should be parsing the query string in that action method. If it can send the requests to multiple locations on your site, then you might consider using an action filter to do the redirect. It is not uncommon to do a redirect after login, the only reason you would need to use routing would be to preserve the URL in the browser that was sent from the SSO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Request.QueryString["action"]` to explicitly get the parameter value from your request url.

```
public ActionResult SingleSignOn(string action)
{
   var querystring = Request.QueryString["action"];
   // Do something with querystring 
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. Definitely better than parsing the querystring manually. But it still seems like I should be about to set up a route to do this better.

Comment: the problem is because your parameter name is same as one the framework uses. If you have the ability to change the querystring key to something else, you can use that as the route parameter and it should work (ex: `actionTodo`)

Comment: Unfortunately, to change the parameter name would be to modify our SSO manager, and then to modify all the other systems that work with it and expect an 'action' parameter, and then regression test the whole ecosystem.  I'll use the Request.QueryString before I'll go down that road.